# Why does the iOS app have an empty feed?

Tags: bug, ios-app

After restoring a backup, my app has an empty feed which remains empty even on refresh and restart. Before restoring the backup, the feed hasn’t been refreshed for a while on the [iPhone XR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_XR).

All other parts of the app work fine.

- App version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 12
- OS version: Version 14.7.1 (build 18G82)

Comment: Ditto on iPad with no Backup https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370424/194412